How to set timeout for an open pool connection?
I am using knex for db connection and keep encountering an error when specified max pool connection reached says Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?
My knex configuration is like following;
const knex = require("knex")({
        client: "pg",
        connection: {
            connectionString: process.env.connection_string,
        },
        pool: {
            min: 0,
            max: 300,
            idleTimeoutMillis: 30000,
            createTimeoutMillis: 30000,
            acquireTimeoutMillis: 30000
            },
        }
    );

knex: "^3.1.0"
pg: "^8.13.0"

Node Version: 18.18.2
nvm: 0.38.0
npm: 9.8.1

What I have observed is some of my pool connections do not close automatically. Is there any way to set timeout for pool connections if the execution takes more then time I specified then stop it and close pool connection. In the configuration I have set idleTimeoutMillis to 30000ms (30 seconds). But I do not think it is working the way I want. I right now have around 100 open pool connections which are open almost for about 2 hours. I am measuring number of used pool connections with knex.client.pool.numUsed(). Do you have any idea?
I see some workaround like;

Downgrading node version. I do not want to do that!
Adding propagateCreateError param to config which is not
recommended by    knex team!

